# Haskell: file to array for Dijkstra's Algorithm

Tags: arrays, haskell, io, functional-programming, haskell-platform

I am building a graph to implement Dijkstra's algorithm and I am reading a file which contains

1 3 5 
1 2 6

How would I read each line and store it as [(a,a,float)]. 
I need this to be able to use:

```
buildGraph :: Ord a => [(a, a, Float)] -> Map a [(a, Float)]
```

Here is How I build my graph:

```
let g =  buildGraph [('a','c',2), ('a','d',6), ('b','a',3)
                         ,('b','d',8), ('c','d',7), ('c','e',5)
                         ,('d','e',10)]
```

Currently I can read the file and store everything in an array.

```
main = do
    contents <- readFile "input.txt"

     print . map readInt . words $ contents


readInt :: String -> Int
readInt = read
```

I want to be able to reach each file and append to an array that will like this ('1','4',5),which is the same as(a,a,float). after the array will be ready to be sent to buildGraph

```
Type Edge = (Char, Char, Float)
readGraphFile :: FilePath -> IO Edge
readGraphFile path = do
                    alldata <- readFile path
                    return (Char,Char,Float)
```

Comment: It will probably be better for you to use something like `Int` or `String` for your nodes; they are just as much in the `Ord` typeclass as `Char`s, but they are not limited to a single digit, so you can support nodes `> 10`.

Comment: @Mike Haskell Char's are 31-bit characters. He isn't any more likely to run out of Nodes than he is with Int.

Comment: @Cubic That's only true if he actually enters all kinds of Unicode characters into the input file. It might look a bit weird. ;-)

Comment: @Mike But then it's still at least 60 different nodes. That's of course not very much, but this probably isn't meant to be a super serious project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something based on the code you gave:

```
import qualified Data.Char as Char -- good practice to import modules qualified

main = do contents <- readFile "input.txt"
          print . map (f . words) $ lines contents
        where
          -- this will break if your input file is badly formed!
          f [a,b,c] = (readChar a, readChar b, readFloat c)

readChar :: String -> Char
readChar c = Char.chr (64 + read c)

readFloat :: String -> Float
readFloat = read
```

The `readChar` function reads a string like `"1"` as an int, then adds 64 (to bring it into the ascii alphanumeric range) and uses the function `Char.chr` to convert it to a character.

You could change the type of `readChar` to e.g. `readOrd :: (Read a, Ord a) => String -> a` to read something more generic.

Of course, you'll have to do something with those values other than print them (e.g. send them to `buildGraph`) or the runtime won't be able to deduce which instance of the intersection `Read ∩ Ord` you want.

This will read the file `input.txt`, which looks like this:

```
1 2 4.5
1 3 6.0
3 2 1.2
```

and output

```
ghci> main
[('A','B',4.5), ('A','C',6.0), ('C','B',1.2)]
```

Comment: @MikeHartl The idea is for e.g. `1` to be interpreted as `'A'`, `2` as `'B'` etc. The question has an input file containing integers, but he seems to want alphabetic characters out.

Comment: Hm... "...an array that will like this `('1','4',5)`,which is the same as `(a,a,float)`" sounded to me like he wanted the `Int`s as Chars.

Comment: @MikeHartl Yeah, reading it again, it's not completely clear what he wants. Oh well!

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: This works! If I wanted to changed it to read 'SJC' 'LAX' 2 then it I should use readOrd :: (Read a, Ord a) =>String ->a?

Comment: It depends what your input file looks like. If a line looks like `SJC LAX 2` then you can replace the definition of `f` with `f [a,b,c] = (a,b,readFloat c)`. You don't need to do anything to `a` and `b` since they're already `String`s.